# passing void to a generic class

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I'm trying to create a form that will animate something while processing a particular task (passed as a delegate to the constructor). It's working fine, but the problem I'm having is that I can't instantiate a copy of my generic class if the particular method that I want to perform has a return type of void.

I understand that this is by design and all, but I'm wondering if there is a known workaround for situations like this.

If it helps at all my windows form looks like so (trimmed for brevity):

```
public partial class operatingWindow<T> : Form
{
    public delegate T Operation();
    private Operation m_Operation;

    private T m_ReturnValue;
    public T ValueReturned { get { return m_ReturnValue; } }

    public operatingWindow(Operation operation) { /*...*/ }
}
```

And I call it like:

```
operatingWindow<int> processing = new operatingWindow<int>(new operatingWindow<int>.Operation(this.doStuff));
processing.ShowDialog();

// ... 
private int doStuff()
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rethink your design slightly.

If you implemented the processing in a base class, you could subclass it with 2 alternatives that would be nearly interchangable.

The first could be like yours, where it takes an Operation that returns a value.  (I would rework this to use `Func<T>` instead of having your own delegate type, though.

The second could just take a simple Action and not provide a return value.  Both could use the same animation/display/etc. routines, but provide a different way of working.  You could also pass this off to other methods using the base class, which would provide a lot of flexibility.

With this approach, you could call this like:

```
private void DoSleep()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(5000);
}
private int ReturnSleep()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(5000);
    return 5000;
}
...
{
    var actionWindow = new OperatingWindowAction(this.DoSleep);
    actionWindow.Execute();
    var funcWindow = new OperatingWindowFunc<int>(this.ReturnSleep);
    funcWindow.Execute();
    int result = funcWindow.Result;
}
```

This would look something like:

```
public abstract partial class OperatingWindowBase : Form
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        // call this.OnExecute(); asyncronously so you can animate
    }
    protected abstract void OnExecute();
}

public class OperatingWindowFunc<T> : OperatingWindowBase
{
    Func<T> operation;
    public T Result { get; private set; }
    public OperatingWindowFunc<T>(Func<T> operation)
    {
        this.operation = operation;
    }
    protected override OnExecute()
    {
        this.Result = operation();
    }
}

public class OperatingWindowAction
{
    Action operation;
    public OperatingWindow(Action operation)
    {
        this.operation = operation;
    }
    protected override OnExecute()
    {
        operation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

No, you'll need to create an overload to do that.

e.g.

```
public operatingWindow(Action action) 
{ 
    m_Operation=() => { action(); return null; }
}
```

Also you don't need to define your own delegate, you can use `Func<T>` and Action.